# How to calculate sum of values stored in getter?

Tags: java, sum

I want to be able to calculate the sum of the int values stored in my getter method. So basically what I want the program to do is to sum the total hours of all the workers into one number. I have no idea how to do this...

The output I get with this code is just the hours for all the workers but not calculated into one sum.

```
for(Employee employee : emloyeeArr) {
  if(employee != null) {                
    System.out.println("Total hours for all the employees:" + 
          employee.getEmployeeHours());
  }
}
```

Comment: Define a variable to hold a running total of the hours, add the hours for each employee in the loop. Print the variable after the loop.

Comment: I suggest stepping back and solving a simpler, related problem: if you have an array of numbers, how do you print the total of those numbers?

Comment: This might help you: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/for-loop/sum-array-of-numbers-with-for-loop/

Comment: thank you for your answer! im very new to this, can you maybe show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Also, a getter doesn't "store" anything. Rather it just returns a value.

Comment: @SofiaNielsen Use `@` to ping a specific person who you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float total_Hours = 0;
for(Employee employee : emloyeeArr) {
 if(employee != null) 
 {
  total_Hours += employee.getEmployeeHours();                      
 }
 System.out.println("Total hours for all the employees:" + 
  total_Hours);
```

All you need to do is run a for loop, get each employee hour and add it in the total then display the total_Hours variable.

Comment: tried it but now the output im getting is just:
Total hours for all the employees:0
Total hours for all the employees:5
Total hours for all the employees:54
Total hours for all the employees:84
Total hours for all the employees:84
Total hours for all the employees:84
Total hours for all the employees:84
Total hours for all the employees:84
Total hours for all the employees:84
Total hours for all the employees:84
Total hours for all the employees:84
Total hours for all the employees:84
Total hours for all the employees:84
...

Comment: the sum 84 is right but how do i stop it from doing so much output?

Comment: i figured it out it just needed a pair of extra brackets, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the employees and sum the hours yourself:

```
long sum = 0L;
for (Employee employee : emloyeeArr) {
    if(employee != null) {
        sum += employee.getEmployeeHours());
    }
}
```

Or, more conveniently, with a stream:

```
long sum = Arrays.stream(emloyeeArr)
                 .filter(Objects::notNull)
                 .mapToInt(Employee:getEmployeeHours)
                 .sum();
```